# CodeIgniter PDO database driver not working

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter, pdo

I'm trying to use the PDO MySQL driver in my CodeIgniter application. This is my database config:

```
$active_group = 'default';
$active_record = TRUE;

$db['default']['hostname'] = 'localhost';
$db['default']['username'] = 'root';
$db['default']['password'] = '';
$db['default']['database'] = 'testdatabase';
$db['default']['dbdriver'] = 'pdo';
$db['default']['dbprefix'] = '';
$db['default']['pconnect'] = TRUE;
$db['default']['db_debug'] = TRUE;
$db['default']['cache_on'] = FALSE;
$db['default']['cachedir'] = '';
$db['default']['char_set'] = 'utf8';
$db['default']['dbcollat'] = 'utf8_general_ci';
$db['default']['swap_pre'] = '';
$db['default']['autoinit'] = TRUE;
$db['default']['stricton'] = FALSE;
```

However, I'm getting this error when I load a controller:

> Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'PDOException' with message 'invalid
>   data source name' in
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\testsite\system\database\drivers\pdo\pdo_driver.php:114

I've checked the data source using `die($this->hostname);` in `pdo_driver.php` and it's coming out as:

```
localhost;dbname=testdatabase
```

so it is getting the correct database name. The database exists and I do have MySQL running.

What could be going wrong here? Thank you.

Comment: Sidenote: I recently read the changelog for the new version (2.1.1) and there are some bugfixes regarding the PDO driver. You might want to check it

Comment: Martin, I am getting a similar error: `Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'PDOException' with message 'could not find driver' in...((several database and core dir/ files listed))... syetem/database/drivers/pdo/pdo_driver.php on line 114`

I'm new enough that I can't even tell if your hack will help me. Where and what **exactly** did you edit in `.../system/database/drivers/pdo/pdo_driver.php`? I'm pretty newbie on config topics. It seems odd to me that a hack to a system file is needed to make PDO work in CI v.2.1.1, doesn't it? Why are (assumedly most) others not needing the hack you mention?

Comment: @govinda, I did mine on line 81, right after the `else { ... }` in the class constructor. It does seem weird that you need to hack it at all but I've found nothing wrong with it since my fix.

Comment: Martin, could you spell it out as a complete thought for me?  I want to be sure if I am hacking a core system file.  Do you mean to say you changed the out-of-the-box line #81 of `.../system/database/drivers/pdo/pdo_driver.php` from this: `empty($this->database) OR $this->hostname .= ';dbname='.$this->database;`, to this: `empty($this->database) OR $this->hostname = 'mysql:dbname='.$this->database.';host='.$this->hostname;`?  Or else could you say it like that? - what line changed from what to what...?

Comment: I put it up on pastebin for you: http://pastebin.com/SzBcdHGr just download that file and replace `/system/database/drivers/pdo/pdo_driver.php` with the one from Pastebin and it should work. Only one line is changed so it should work out of the box.

Comment: thanks for doing that!  When I try that copy, I get this error:
`A PHP Error was encountered

Severity: Warning

Message: PDO::__construct() [pdo.--construct]: [2002] Can't assign requested address (trying to connect via tcp://localhost:/tmp/mysql.sock:3306)

Filename: pdo/pdo_driver.php

Line Number: 114

Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'PDOException' with message 'SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] Can't assign requested address' in 
../system/database/drivers/pdo/pdo_driver.php:114 Stack trace: #0 
`
...plus:

Comment: `../system/database/drivers/pdo/pdo_driver.php(114): PDO->__construct('mysql:dbname=GM...', 'root', '', Array) #1 
../system/database/DB_driver.php(115): CI_DB_pdo_driver->db_pconnect() #2 
../system/database/DB.php(148): CI_DB_driver->initialize() #3 
../system/core/Loader.php(346): DB('', NULL) #4 
../system/core/Loader.php(1171): CI_Loader->database() #5 
../system/core/Loader.php(152): CI_Loader->_ci_autoloader() #6 /Library/WebServer/Documents/GMDO_phase3_l in 
../system/database/drivers/pdo/pdo_driver.php on line 114`

Comment: ...which is similar to what i get when I try various (unsuccessful) guesses at what should be the value of `$db['local_dev']['hostname']` in my database config.  If you have any more ideas, I would love to hear them.  BTW, there were a few differences between our copies of `/system/database/drivers/pdo/pdo_driver.php`, here is mine: http://pastebin.com/hV9Ezaqp  The diff on line # 192 you might find esp. interesting.  I get over my head quick, so you better have a look yourself.  Let me know what you think about that.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

This should not be the case.

```
localhost;dbname=testdatabase
```

should be

```
mysql:dbname=testdatabase;host=localhost;
```

Comment: Thanks, I modified the CodeIgniter PDO driver to this: `$this->hostname = 'mysql:dbname='.$this->database.';host='.$this->hostname;` and it seems to work now. :)

Comment: Modifying the core driver is unnecessary, and will break the next time you update CI unless you remember to make the change to the core file again. Take the approach below, editing your database settings file instead.

Answer (score 29):

On file **/application/config/database.php** where is

```
$db['default']['hostname'] = 'localhost';
```

must be

```
$db['default']['hostname'] = 'mysql:host=localhost';
```

*localhost* or your database host.

Comment: Doh. Of course it should. I just presumed CI would handle it off the bat.

Comment: Strictly speaking, that's not a hostname. The proper approach is to provide a value for dsn in the db config as described in the answer below.

Answer (score 7):

PDO driver require a full DSN string to be provided. 
The string like this

```
'dsn' = ‘mysql:host=localhost;dbname=databasename’;
```

when you use this string you should remove host and databasename value from array. 
I think following example gives you an idea.

```
$db['default'] = array(
'dsn'   => 'mysql:host=localhost;dbname=codeigniter3',
'hostname' => '',
'username' => 'root',
'password' => '',
'database' => '',
'dbdriver' => 'pdo',
'dbprefix' => '',
'pconnect' => FALSE,
'db_debug' => TRUE,
'cache_on' => FALSE,
'cachedir' => '',
'char_set' => 'utf8',
'dbcollat' => 'utf8_general_ci',
'swap_pre' => '',
'encrypt' => FALSE,
'compress' => FALSE,
'stricton' => FALSE,
'failover' => array(),
'save_queries' => TRUE
);
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

According to CodeIgniter's [Database Configuration](http://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/database/configuration.html) page,

For the PDO driver, you should change the '**`hostname => 'localhost'`**' to   "**`'hostname' => mysql:host=localhost`**" like below:

```
$db['default'] = array(
    'dsn'   => '',
    'hostname' => 'mysql:host=localhost',
    'username' => 'root',
    'password' => '',
    'database' => 'database_name',
    'dbdriver' => 'pdo',
    'dbprefix' => '',
    'pconnect' => FALSE,
    'db_debug' => (ENVIRONMENT !== 'production'),
     .....
     .....
);
```