# codeigniter 3.1 PDO mysql Error Number: 3D000/1046 No database selected

Tags: mysql, pdo, codeigniter-3

I had issue with upgrading codeignier 2.xx to 3.xx before and I can not found any completed answer for me. So I'd like to share how I solved it.

In Codeignier official web site show how to connect PDO with Mysql as below

> For the PDO driver, you should use the $config[‘dsn’] setting instead
>   of ‘hostname’ and ‘database’:
>
> $config[‘dsn’] = ‘mysql:host=localhost;dbname=mydatabase’

https://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/database/connecting.html

But I still could not make it work as it was showing error

> Invalid or non-existent PDO subdriver

Some site shown how to fixe this by add this to hostname

> $db ['default'] ['hostname'] = 'mysql:host=localhost';

But I still got error

> Error Number: 3D000/1046
>
> No database selected

Answer (score 6):

I spend time to debug a while I found that once dbdriver is selected to 'pdo' Codeigniter check dsn detail from $db ['default'] ['hostname'] not in 
$db ['default'] ['dns']  including database name like below.

> $db ['default'] ['hostname'] =
>   'mysql:host=localhost;dbname=my_database';

I hope this will help for anyone may got error like mine.

Answer (score 6):

My config:

```
    'dsn'   => 'mysql:host=localhost;dbname=codeigniter3',
    'dbdriver' => 'pdo'
```

You can see here:
[CodeIgniter PDO database driver not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11054618/codeigniter-pdo-database-driver-not-working)