# Can't connect my database on Hosting

Tags: php, mysql, database, codeigniter, hosting

This is my connection:

Using *CodeIgniter*

```
$db['mysql'] = array(   
'dsn' => 'mysql:host=SOMEHOSTNAME;dbname=SOMEDATABASE',
'hostname' => 'SOMEHOSTNAME',
'username' => 'SOME USER',
'password' => 'password',
'database' => 'SOME DATABASE',
'dbdriver' => 'pdo',

);
```

This is my localhost conection

```
$db['mysql'] = array(
'dsn'   => 'mysql:hostname=localhost; dbname=1410inventory',
'hostname' => '',
'username' => 'root',
'password' => '',
'database' => '',
'dbdriver' => 'pdo',
```

);

My log pulls this:

> ERROR - 2018-07-23 19:36:18 --> PDO: Invalid or non-existent subdriver

Please Help
Edit:This is a test DB.

Comment: Hi German Mendieta.  Do **NOT** post database connection details on the web!!!  I removed what was in the question.  I *strongly* suggest you flush all data in there and put back some backup you have (you have one right?).  God knows what is in that database now!

Comment: As for your question, where does the code run?  Is it in the same hoster environment as the database?  Are remote connections allowed by this provider?  The ones I use will not allow any remote connection to their database, only locally running code.

Comment: And search is your friend: https://forum.codeigniter.com/archive/index.php?thread-65419.html and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32836797/codeigniter-3-1-pdo-mysql-error-number-3d000-1046-no-database-selected and others.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I hardly recommend you not to use PDO driver since it is slower and you don't have all the codeigniter query builders (more info [here](https://forum.codeigniter.com/thread-64268.html)). Instead I recommend you use msqli driver, and it would look like this:

```
$active_group = 'default';
$query_builder = TRUE;

$db['default'] = array(
    'dsn'   => '',
    'hostname' => 'localhost',
    'username' => 'SomeUserName',
    'password' => 'SomePass',
    'database' => '1410inventory',
    'dbdriver' => 'mysqli',
    'pconnect' => FALSE,
    'db_debug' => (ENVIRONMENT !== 'development'), //change to production when needed
    'cache_on' => FALSE,
    'cachedir' => '',
    'char_set' => 'utf8',
    'dbcollat' => 'utf8_general_ci',
    'swap_pre' => '',
    'encrypt' => FALSE,
    'compress' => FALSE,
    'stricton' => FALSE,
    'failover' => array(),
    'save_queries' => TRUE
);
```

If you're still wanting to use PDO just remove the last comma after `'dbdriver' => 'pdo',` like this `'dbdriver' => 'pdo'` since it's the last element of your array there's no need to put an extra comma and change `hostname` for `host` so your localhost connection should look like

```
$db['mysql'] = array( 
'dsn'    => 'mysql:host=host_name;dbname=1410inventory',
'username' => 'usr',
'password' => 'pw',
'database' => '1410inventory',
'dbdriver' => 'pdo' );
```